# How to create a timer that starts as soon as something is put into the input field

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a timer that goes up (1,2,3,4,5) instead of down (5,4,3,2,1), but I want the timer to stay at 00:00. The timer can only start running when the user inserts something in the input field. I have this, but i'm not sure how to create the timer loop. The research I have done only brought up stuff about counters going down and it was related to python. So I kind of was hoping the sam ecould be achieved in javascript. the input field is created like this-> (it will later increment by name/id, because it can duplicate)

```
        var sylInput = $('<input/>', {
        'type': 'text',
        'class': 'form-control syl-input',
        'id': 'testid'
    });
```

this is my variable->

```
var T = '';
```

and this is the html where the timer and etc. will be made->

```
<div class="col-md-2" id="timer"></div>
```

my apologies if this is a newbie question 101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var T = '';

    T = new TIMER('#timer');

  $(document).one('keydown', '.HereComesTheClassNameOfYourInputField', function(){
T.start();
});
```

the html:

```
 <div class="col-md-2" id="timer"></div>
```

if someone else wants to use this: Note that you do have to style ur timer first.

Answer (score 1):

ok I assume you use jQuery

```
let timer; 
let counter = 0;

function startTimer(){
    counter++;
    $("#timer").text(counter);
}

$(document).on('keypress', '#inputID', function() {
   if (timer !== undefined) //check if is already set
   timer = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
});
```